# How to: grunt task modularization

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I have the following grunt task

```
 grunt.registerTask('pack', ['clean', 'makeMdirs', 'prepare:test']);
 grunt.registerTask('pack-ci', ['clean', 'makeMdirs', 'prepare:ci']);
```

Notice how they differ only in their arguments to the prepare task? How do I make this modular so that I can just have one pack task that passes in an argument to prepare function.

Answer (score 0):

Using a custom task, you can evaluate arguments passed into the task via the command line and adjust the execution of tasks.  This function would allow you to use `grunt pack` with an optional `--ci` flag to toggle between the different prepare targets:

```
function oneTaskToRuleThemAll() {
        var prepareTarget = ['prepare', (grunt.option('ci') ? 'ci': 'test')].join(':');
        grunt.task.run(['clean', 'makeMdirs', prepareTarget]);
    }

    grunt.registerTask('pack', oneTaskToRuleThemAll);
```